# How to convert date in Oracle?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have sql query in MySQL:

```
SELECT
   distinct 
   us.user_id as user_id, 
   us.ab_id,
   users.name,
   users.role,
   users.is_admin,
   DATE_FORMAT('2013-11-05T10:06:21+04:00', '%Y-%m') as month_m
FROM attach_offices as us
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = user_id
WHERE us.`ab_id` = 999999999 and
 DATE_FORMAT('2013-11-05T10:06:21+04:00', '%Y-%m') between DATE_FORMAT(dt_begin, '%Y-%m') and DATE_FORMAT(`dt_end`, '%Y-%m')
```

How to convert it to Oracle 11g? I write something like this:

```
SELECT 
     distinct 
   attach_offices.user_id as user_id, 
   attach_offices.ab_id,
   users.name,
   users.role,
   users.is_admin,
   to_date('2013-11-05T10:06:21+04:00', 'YYYY-MM') as month_m       
FROM attach_offices 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = user_id
WHERE attach_offices.ab_id = 999999999 and
 to_date('2013-11-05T10:06:21+04:00', 'YYYY-MM') between to_date(to_char(dt_begin, 'YYYY-MM'), 'YYYY-MM') and to_date(to_char(dt_end, 'YYYY-MM'), 'YYYY-MM')
```

But it does not work.
The problem in date, when i use `2013-11-05T10:06:21+04:00` it does not work but when i use `2013-11` it is work

Answer (score 1):

Because `TO_DATE` will convert given `STRING` to `DATE` by format, you have specified.
`DATE_FORMAT` however formats DATE as specified.

So you have following options:
1. If you want to get desired `DATE` as some special crafted `STRING`, then you go with `TO_CHAR(DATE, '<format>')`
2. If you want to convert given `STRING` to `DATE`, you go with `TO_DATE(string,'<format that describes string>')`.
3. If you need one special crafted `STRING` reformat as another `STRING`, then you do both. First convert it to date, as described in **2**, then convert back to string, as described in **1** with needed format.
4. And one more case - if you want to change output format, then you need to ALTER SESSION variable NLS_DATE_FORMAT.

Answer (score -1):

i am do something like this but it seems not DRY  and code smell:

```
SELECT 
   distinct 
   attach_offices.user_id as user_id, 
   attach_offices.ab_id,
   users.name,
   users.role,
   users.is_admin,
   to_date(to_char(to_date('2013-11-05T10:06:21+04:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"+04:00"'), 'YYYY-MM'),'YYYY-MM') as month_m         
FROM attach_offices 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = user_id
WHERE attach_offices.ab_id = 999999999 and
to_date(to_char(to_date('2013-11-05T10:06:21+04:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"+04:00"'), 'YYYY-MM'),'YYYY-MM') between to_date(to_char(dt_begin, 'YYYY-MM'), 'YYYY-MM') and to_date(to_char(dt_end, 'YYYY-MM'), 'YYYY-MM')
```

Comment: Use comments to ask for more information and you can edit your question to update it with more details. As for the following code question number one is where do you get this date string from? And is it really comes as a string? What you want to get as select result?